# Add read-only user to a specific folder of an existing sFTP server

Tags: linux, sftp

I have set up an sFTP server with a group *sftp_only*. The users belonging to this group can read everywhere within the folder structure /srv/sftp/project_data/

I used to add a user via the following cmd:
`sudo useradd --no-create-home --home-dir /srv/sftp --groups sftp_only username`
`sudo passwd username`

now I would like to create a new user which has read-only permissions only in a specific folder: */srv/sftp/project_data/data*

I created the user *ro_user* and I added it to the *sftp_only* group.

Then I inserted the following lines to my ssd_config file

```
Match User gleam_ro
    ChrootDirectory /srv/sftp/project_data/data
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTTY no
    PermitTunnel no
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

but when I try to connect to the server it is not landing in the */srv/sftp/project_data/data/* folder but in the */srv/sftp/project_data* one and it can open all the other folders below.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516326/17660) might show a simpler method. Does it apply to your case?

Comment: Do you have other "match" sections in sshd_config that would apply to this user?

Comment: Hi, under Linux when you give reading/writing/access to a group you give to each user belonging to it. Maybe you can give the ownership of  `/srv/sftp/project_data/data` to  your _ro_user_ with _ro_user_group_, and insert  _sftp_(NOT_ANYMORE)_only_  also into _ro_user_group_ ...

Comment: @Kenster no I don't have any other math user section in my file

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately it does not apply to me because I would like that the user could see only the folder /srv/sftp/project_data/data

Comment: Do you mean to say that the `ChrootDirectory` does not work correctly? Which SFTP server are you using?

Comment: Also - check what you did against [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154689/17660).